# Active record query interface in Ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can somebody assist on how I  can write this  custom query and an Active  Record query interface, I am still brand new to Ruby  and I read that Active record interface query  works on most databases so its recommended. Thank you in advance

```
sql = "select count(distinct(email)) as rcount from resources r
           inner join capabilities c
           on c.resource_id = r.id
           inner join skills s
           on c.skill_id = s.id "
sql += " where " unless (params[:country_id].to_i.zero? && params[:skill_id].to_i.zero?)

sql += "r.nationality = '" + Country.get_country_name(params[:country_id]) + "'" unless (params[:country_id].to_i.zero?)

sql += " and " unless (params[:country_id].to_i.zero? || params[:skill_id].to_i.zero?)

sql += "s.id =" + params[:skill_id] unless (params[:skill_id].to_i.zero?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your model's relationships are set correctly. Here is an `ActiveRecord` translation of your sql.

```
Resource.select(:email).joins(capabilities: :skills).distinct.count
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ActiveRecord::Querying#find_by_sql` directly on your model.

Example:

```
Post.find_by_sql "SELECT p.title, c.author FROM posts p, comments c WHERE p.id = c.post_id"
```